# C# WPF listBox vertical alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, alignment

I have a listBox with a checkbox I want to manage the alignment through setting the vertical alignment.

[image]

I have seen several solution here e.g. set verticalContentAlignment or verticalAlignment to top but that didn't work.

I've also seen some setting a style but couldn't manage to make it done.

What I'd like is to know WHY the ONLY element is down there. I can't understand why it's stuck in the middle.

Here's my code:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lb2Tab3"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.8,0"  >
     <CheckBox x:Name="cbEasyRunManagesPcDmis" Margin="20"  Content="EasyRun Manages PC-DMIS" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="cbTouchScreen_Click" />
 </ListBox>
```

thanx for any help
Patrick

--- EDIT ---
As requested by Frisbee here is the complete xaml. Sorry for its length:

```
<Base:WindowViewBase x:Class="EasyRun.Views.MainView.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"                
    xmlns:Base="clr-namespace:Cannoli.Base;assembly=Cannoli"
    xmlns:design="clr-namespace:EasyRun.Views.MainView.Design"
            xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
            xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            xmlns:CannoliBorderlessWindow="clr-namespace:CannoliBorderlessWindow;assembly=Cannoli.BorderlessWindow"
    d:DesignWidth="212.32" d:DesignHeight="109.92"
            Title="EASY RUN 2.0"  Height="600" Width="900"  MinWidth="500" FontFamily="/EasyRun2.0;component/Resources/Fonts/#FontAwesome" Icon="/EasyRun2.0;component/Resources/Images/Lightning.png"          
    >

<d:WindowViewBase.DataContext>
    <design:DesignMainViewModel />
</d:WindowViewBase.DataContext>

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <CannoliBorderlessWindow:CannoliBorderlessWindowBehavior/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>

<!-- RISORSE GLOBALI: VARIABILI -->
<Window.Resources>
    <System:Double x:Key="BUTTON_HEIGHT">50</System:Double>
    <System:Double x:Key="BUTTON_FONTSIZE">20</System:Double>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/EasyRun2.0;component/Resources/Images/gradientWallpaper.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeMessage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="428,128,99.6,228"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left"  Margin="0,0,-0.4,0" Background="{x:Null}">
        <!-- +++++++++++++ TAB1 ++++++++++++ -->
        <TabItem  Name="tabItem1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="80" FontSize="50" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Text="&#xF0A7;"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="tbTab1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="20"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="Border1Tab1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" Width="200" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Margin="10,10,10,10.4" >
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbButtons1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Border2Tab1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" MinWidth="100" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,9.2,10" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <!-- +++++++++++++ TAB2 ++++++++++++ -->
        <TabItem Name="tabItem2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="80"  FontSize="50">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="&#xF0F7;"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="tbTab2" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="20"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush/>
            </TabItem.Background>
        </TabItem>
        <!-- +++++++++++++ TAB3 ++++++++++++ -->
        <TabItem Name="tabItem3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="80" FontSize="50" Background="{x:Null}" >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="&#xF013;" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                    <TextBlock Name="tbTab3" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="20"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>

            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="Border1Tab3" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" Width="200" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Margin="10,10,10,10" >
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbButtons3"  FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  >
                        <Button Name="bt1Tab3" Background="{x:Null}"   Content="1" Click="Button_Click" />
                        <Button Name="bt2Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}"  Content="2" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="bt3Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}"  Content="3" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="bt4Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}"  Content="4" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="bt5Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}"  Content="5" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="bt6Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}"  Content="6" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="bt7Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}"  Content="7" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="bt8Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}"  Content="8" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    </ListBox>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Border2Tab3" BorderBrush="Gainsboro"  MinWidth="100" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10"  >
                    <StackPanel >
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb1Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.4,0" d:IsHidden="True"  >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="lbLanguage" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"><Run Text="Language"/></TextBlock>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbLanguages" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="246" Height="35" DropDownClosed="cmbLanguages_DropDownClosed"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="cbTouchScreen" Margin="20"  Content="Use touch screen" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="cbTouchScreen_Click" />
                            <CheckBox x:Name="cbEnableImages" Margin="20"  Content="Enable Images" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel Name="spImageDimension" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="lbImageDimension" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"  TextAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Image dimension"/></TextBlock>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbImageDimension" Margin="20" Text="250 px" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   DropDownClosed="cmbImageDimension_DropDownClosed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="246" Height="35" IsEditable="True">
                                    <TextBlock ><Run Text="50 px"/></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock ><Run Text="100 px"/></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock ><Run Text="150 px"/></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock ><Run Text="200 px"/></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock ><Run Text="250 px"/></TextBlock>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBox>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb2Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.8,0"  >
                            <CheckBox x:Name="cbEasyRunManagesPcDmis" Margin="20"  Content="EasyRun Manages PC-DMIS" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="cbTouchScreen_Click" />
                        </ListBox>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb3Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.4,0"  />
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb4Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.4,0" d:IsHidden="True"  >
                        </ListBox>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb5Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.4,0" d:IsHidden="True"  >
                        </ListBox>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb6Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.4,0" d:IsHidden="True"  >
                        </ListBox>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb7Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.4,0" d:IsHidden="True"  >
                        </ListBox>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb8Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,0,0.4,0" d:IsHidden="True"  >
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>


        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: are you sure that this is an issue with the `CheckBox ` from what I see the background of the `ListBox` is null so this background is coming from somewhere else. Put some color to the `ListBox ` to see if it's on the whole page or it's down there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was related with the fact that there are several listBox one on top of the other. I thought that making them hidden was enough but when I painted the second listBox in black I saw that it was not starting from the top (see image).

[image]

So the solution was to set Visibility = Collapsed for all the listbox that are not in use. 
Thanks to  kirotab for putting me on the right path. Not sure if I can vote your comment.

Comment: Glad that you worked it out and sorry that I couldn't help more, but it's always sweeter when you solve your issues yourself so maybe that was for the better. By the way have that in mind if you use another platform, all of them seem similar, so for example in Android or Web (HTML) you have option that only hides the element, and one that hides it but also removes it from the structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to align the ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb2Tab3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
```

If that does not work then post more of your XAML